# Table of contents in compliance with usability.gov 7.3

Tags: html, css, links, navigation, menu

I'm trying to make the long pages on my site comply with usability.gov section 7:3 which is described here:

https://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/rules/usegov7.3/

So I went ahead and started my navigation code right under the body tag. I titled my navigation ToC because its later converted to a pop-up bubble off to the side of the page (to not interfere with user navigation).

Here's the fragment of my navigation code:

```
<body ID="t">
    <div ID="sb">
    <p ID="sbac">ToC</p>
    <ol ID="sbm">
        <li><a ID="x1" href="faqs/#sb1">Ordering Tickets</a></li>
        <li><a ID="x2" href="faqs/#sb2">Pricing and Dates</a></li>
        <li><a ID="x3" href="faqs/#sb3">Attendance requirements</a></li>
        <li><a ID="x4" href="faqs/#sb4">COVID-19 related</a></li>
        <li><a ID="x5" href="faqs/#sb5">Ticket platforms</a></li>
        <li><a ID="x6" href="faqs/#sb6">Other Questions</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The attached image is what one would see when reloading my page with CSS turned off:

[image: Sample of browser result without CSS]

With CSS on, the page looks pretty.

So with my menu at the top both in code and on-screen with CSS off, why would the sortsite tools complain that I'm not providing links to content further down the page?